# Reverse for 'invite' with arguments '('tk-test',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have an invite_user view that looks like this:

```
class invite_user(View):

    template_name = "invites/invite.html"


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = InviteForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = InviteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(form.cleaned_data['first_name'], form.cleaned_data['email'], '**')
            user.first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            #now make invite
            invite = Invite.objects.create(user=user, cookie='ck-test', token='tk-test')
            send_mail('Subject', 'Link: http://somesite.com%s' % invite.get_absolute_url(), [user.email])
            return redirect(reverse('home_page'))
        else:
            form = InviteForm()
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

When running, django is telling me it cannot find an invite object with the argument 'tk-test'. I am a bit confused here, since I am clearly making an instance of Invite with  token='tk-test'. I may be confused with what get_absolute_url should be used for.

Here is the model:

```
class Invite(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    cookie = models.SlugField()
    token = models.SlugField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s's invite" % (self.user)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return (reverse('invite', args=[self.token]))
```

I can provide some middleware that is being used, too, but that seems irrelevant here unless requested. Can someone explain what is going on here?

My main URLConf as requested:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
from project.apps.blog.views import home, about
from project.apps.suggest.views import suggest, thankyou
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from project.userprofile.views import Login, Logout, Signup
from porject.apps.invites.views import invite_user
#used for serving static locally
from django.conf import settings



urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    #blog app
    url(r'^$', home.as_view(), name="home_page"),
    url(r'^about/$', about.as_view(), name='about_page'),

    #suggest app
    url(r'^suggest/$', suggest.as_view(), name='suggest_page'),
    url(r'^thankyou/$', thankyou.as_view(), name='thank_you_page'),

    #userprofile
    url(r'^login/$', Login.as_view(), name='login_page'),
    url(r'^logout/$', Logout.as_view(), name='logout_page'),
    url(r'^signup/$', Signup.as_view(), name='signup_page'),

    #invite app
    url(r'^request-invite/$', invite_user.as_view(), name="invite_user_page"),



)
```

Comment: Have you included your app urls.py in main conf urls.py?

Comment: Yes, it is directly in my main URLconf as such `url(r'^request-invite/$', invite_user.as_view(), name="invite_user_page"),`

Comment: Can you post your `urls.py` code?  You are most likely missing the `arg` there

Comment: Please post your main `URLconf`, it looks like you don't have entry for the url name `invite`, do you?

Comment: I have posted my main URLconf in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an entry for the URL named `invite` as you are using it in `get_absolute_url` of model `Invite`. If you have defined the view for that model you should add the URL entry. If this model does not have any view then you don't need to define `get_absolute_url`. As to what exactly `get_absolute_url` is for read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url)

Comment: Oh god, thanks for pointing that out. I totally forgot about that. And thank you for the link.